# Como faço para visualizar o responsável com os dependentes

Tags: php, html, mysql

Meu *select* está errado. Como faço para visualizar os dependentes deste usuário: eu tenho 1 usuário: (Mauro Santos) e 2 Dependentes: (Thiago e Dhalila), como faço para visualizar na *view*.

## Select

```
SELECT * FROM cad_lideranca WHERE numerocontrato = :numerocontrato
```

## Código da View

```
<?php

require_once './config.php';
include './header.php';
try {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM cad_lideranca WHERE numerocontrato = :numerocontrato";
   $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindValue(":numerocontrato", intval($_GET["numerocontrato"]));

   $stmt->execute();
   $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}

?>

<div class="row">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="index.php">Início</a></li>
      <li class="active">Informações</li>
    </ul>
</div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Informações</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" name="contact_form" id="contact_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="process_form.php">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="required"></span>Número do Contrato:</label>
              <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" readonly="" placeholder="Número do Contrato" value="<?php echo $results[0]["numerocontrato"] ?>" id="numerocontrato" class="form-control" name="numerocontrato"><span class="error"></span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="required"></span>Responsável:</label>
              <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" readonly="" value="<?php echo $results[0]["nomecompleto"] ?>" placeholder="Responsável" id="nome_completo" class="form-control" name="nome_completo"><span class="error"></span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="required"></span>E-mail:</label>
              <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" readonly="" value="<?php echo $results[0]["email"] ?>" placeholder="E-mail" id="email" class="form-control" name="email"><span class="error"></span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="required"></span>Estado:</label>
              <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" readonly="" value="<?php echo $results[0]["estado"] ?>" placeholder="Estado" id="email" class="form-control" name="email"><span class="error"></span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="required"></span>Valor da Adesão:</label>
              <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" readonly="" value="<?php echo $results[0]["adesao"] ?>" placeholder="Adesão" id="adesao" class="form-control" name="adesao"><span class="error"></span>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-4 control-label"><span class="required"></span>Valor Total:</label>
              <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input type="text" readonly="" value="<?php echo $results[0]["total"] ?>" placeholder="Total" id="total" class="form-control" name="total"><span class="error"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- DEPENDENTES -->



  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Dependentes</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

      <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;" >
        <form action="index.php" method="get" >
        <div class="col-lg-6 pull-left"style="padding-left: 0;"  >
          <span class="pull-left">  
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php if ($results > 0) { ?>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered ">
            <tbody><tr>
                <th>Nome do Dependente</th>
                <th>CPF</th>
                <th>Plano </th>
                <th>Acomodação </th>
                <th>Grau Parentesco </th>
                <th>Valor do Dependente </th>


              </tr>
  <?php foreach ($results as $res) { ?>
                <tr>

                  <td><?php echo $res["nomedependente"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $res["cpfdependente"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $res["planodependente"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $res["acomodacaodependente"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $res["grauparentescodependente"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $res["valordependente"]; ?></td>

                </tr>
  <?php } ?>
            </tbody></table>
        </div>


          <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="well well-lg"><b>Nenhum dependente encontrado.</b></div>
<?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Banco

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## View

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloca o código da view tbm

Comment: Se entendi direito vc deve fazer a pesquisa pelo número do contranto e não pelo id. Sua consulta pelo id retorna quantos registros? testou ela direto no banco?

Comment: pelo id me retorna todos os resultados, e pelo numerocontrato também

Comment: Esse `id` é do dependente certo? qual é o campo que associa o dependente ao responsavel? número do contrato?

Comment: o id é do responsável, o que associa o dependente é o numero do contrato

Comment: Pelo design dessa tabela você não pode fazer a pesquisa pelo id, vai ter que pesquisar pelo numerocontrato. Se quiser melhorar o sistema pode normalizar a tabela, criando outra tabela para os dependentes, e fazer a ligação pelo id de ambas as tabelas.

Comment: Pode criar uma tabela tipo pessoa para indicar se é responsável ou dependente

Comment: A coluna não está errada? Em vez de SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE 1 AND id = :numerocontrato, não deveria ser SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE 1 AND numerocontrato = :numerocontrato?

Comment: Ta certo @TiagoGomes, eu to pegando pelo id o numero do contrato e tentando visualizar o total de dependentes pelo numero do contrato

Comment: Qual select está correto o que está em separado ou o que está na view?

Comment: Fiz a pesquisa no phpmyadmin e ele ta me passando os valores corretos, mas não sei qual o problema agora que o resultado não esta sendo visualizado na view @TiagoGomes

Comment: qual o resultado lhe dá quando faz echo $sql; ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM cad_lideranca WHERE numerocontrato = :numerocontrato @TiagoGomes

Comment: Pois tabem, desculpe. e o echo $_GET["numerocontrato"]; e o echo intval($_GET["numerocontrato"]);

Comment: deve ser o intval que deve tranformar o 001 para 1 e assim não encontra nenhum

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50741/discussion-between-mauro-santos-and-tiago-gomes).

Comment: @Mauro Santos o chat já não está online. Pode fazer a questão aqui :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando está adicionar o valor ao SQL está indicar que é o numero (intval) isso quer dizer que está a tirar os zeros à esquerda.

Alterar de.:

```
$stmt->bindValue(":numerocontrato", intval($_GET["numerocontrato"]));
```

Para.:

```
$stmt->bindValue(":numerocontrato", $_GET["numerocontrato"]);
```

Ultrapassará o constrangimento.